# Проблема с MultiValueDictKeyError?

Tags: python, django

В процессе обучения... 
Есть база данных. Выводим информацию из нее по фильтрам в html
Нужно было сделать поиск по базе в той же странице - по urls не должно меняться - т.е. при перекидывании на страницу результатов поиск адрес остается тот же...
Собственнно вот вылетает такая ошибка

```
ponse
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\django\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\django\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\django\test_django\courses_django\lesson_sixth\views.py", line 39, in post
    query = request.POST['search']
  File "F:\django\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 80, in __getit
em__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'search'
[02/May/2019 17:21:23] "POST /lesson-sixth/ HTTP/1.1" 500 82460
```

вот views.py

```
    def post(self, request):
        query = request.POST['search']
        result_list = Human.objects.filter(company=query)
        if result_list.count() != 0:
            context = {
                'result_list': result_list,
                'query': query,
            }
        else:
            context = {
            'empty': "Ничего не найдено :(",
            'query': query,
           }

        return render(request, 'result.html', context)
```

Вот result.html

```
{% extends 'human_list.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Форма поиска</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="">Введите компанию</label>
  <input type="search" type='text'>
  <button type="submit" >Найти</button>
</form>
<h2>Результат поиска по '{{query}}'</h2>

{% if empty %}
<p style = 'font-size: 32px;color: red;'>{{empty}}</p>
{% endif %}
<table border = '1'>
  <tr style = 'background : yellow; color: black; '>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>Фамилия</td>
    <td>Дата рождения</td>
    <td>Компания</td>
    <td>Должность</td>
    <td>Язык програмирования</td>
    <td>Зарплата</td>
  </tr>
  {% for elem in result_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{elem.name}}</td>
    <td>{{elem.surname}}</td>
    <td>{{elem.birth}}</td>
    <td>{{elem.company}}</td>
    <td>{{elem.position}}</td>
    <td>{{elem.language}}</td>
    <td>{{elem.salary}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

вот файл human_list.html  (кусок на что ссылается request.POST['search']

```
  <h2>Форма поиска</h2>
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="">Введите компанию</label>
    <input type="search" type='text'>
    <button type="submit" >Найти</button>
  </form>
```

Вот что выдала консоль на запись перед query в 40 строке  print(request.POST)

```css
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\django\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inne
r
    response = get_response(request)
  File "F:\django\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_res
ponse
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "F:\django\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_res
ponse
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\django\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\django\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\django\test_django\courses_django\lesson_sixth\views.py", line 41, in post
    query = request.POST['search']
  File "F:\django\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 80, in __getit
em__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'search'
[03/May/2019 00:28:26] "POST /lesson-sixth/ HTTP/1.1" 500 82503
```

[![5][1]][1]

Тут и застрял...((

вот result.html

```css
{% extends 'human_list.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Форма поиска</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="">Введите компанию</label>
  <input type="search" type='text'>
  <button type="submit" >Найти</button>
</form>
<h2>Результат поиска по '{{query}}'</h2>

{% if empty %}
<p style = 'font-size: 32px;color: red;'>{{empty}}</p>
{% endif %}
<table border = '1'>
  <tr style = 'background : yellow; color: black; '>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>Фамилия</td>
    <td>Дата рождения</td>
    <td>Компания</td>
    <td>Должность</td>
    <td>Язык програмирования</td>
    <td>Зарплата</td>
  </tr>
  {% for elem in result_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{elem.name}}</td>
    <td>{{elem.surname}}</td>
    <td>{{elem.birth}}</td>
    <td>{{elem.company}}</td>
    <td>{{elem.position}}</td>
    <td>{{elem.language}}</td>
    <td>{{elem.salary}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Вот models.py

```css
from django.db import models

class Human(models.Model):

    CHOICE_COMPANY = (
        ('google', 'Google'),
        ('yandex', 'Yandex'),
        ('itvdn', 'Itvdn'),
        ('epam', 'Epam'),
    )
    POSITION_CHOICE = (
        ("senior", 'Senior'),
        ('middle', 'Middle'),
        ('junior', 'Junior')
    )

    PYTHON = 'python'
    JAVASCRIPT = 'javascript'
    CS = 'c#'
    CPP = 'cpp'

    LANGUAGE_CHOICE = (
        (PYTHON , 'Python'),
        (JAVASCRIPT , 'Javascript'),
        (CS , 'C#'),
        (CPP , 'C++'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Имя')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=CHOICE_COMPANY)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=POSITION_CHOICE)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICE ,   default=PYTHON)
    salary = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Имя - {0} , Фамилия - {1} , Компания - {2}'.format(self.name, self.surname, self.company)
```

Comment: покажите, что в `request.POST()`

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0  добавил - вы это имели ввиду ?

Comment: Нет. Во `views.py` перед `query = request.POST['search']` напишите `print(request.POST)` и покажите, что выдаст консоль.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 добавил. Вставил print как Вы и сказали

Comment: @Дмитрий так вывод print'а перед этой ошибкой до сих пор не добавили

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0  не так силен как Вы (( Но сделал все в точности как было написано. На скрине 40 строка

Comment: @Дмитрий ну сделайте этот `post` запрос и посмотрите в консоль

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 так я все выложил - ответ не меняется... Выше скрина выполнялся код - вот и ответ

Comment: @Дмитрий Вы явно что-то не то делаете. Там должен быть словарь джанговский.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 вам нужно показать значение по словарю ? ['search'] Я правильно понимаю ?

Comment: @Дмитрий сам словарь

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 как таковой словарь представляет собой базу данных. ФИ,дата рождения, язык программирования,компания, зарплата. Заносилось все с админ панели и потом со страницы HTML - по ней и работает ' search'. Выше добавил код

Comment: причем тут бд... изучайте отладку, короче, а то что горохом об стену.